# Looks like 12 gauge into box with two switches - looks like 14 gauge going out

Tags: electrical, wiring

We just bought a new (to us) house (built in the early 90s) and I was replacing a couple of switches in one box.  It is a 20 amp circuit and the hot wire coming into the box is 12 gauge (I measured with calipers).  The switches control a small light fixture over the sink.   The second goes down to an outlet  under the sink but wasn't used.   We are planning to use it for a garbage disposal.

The wires running from the switches both look small and measure smaller with my calipers so I am pretty sure they are 14 gauge.  I pulled the cover on the next outlet downstream and it looks to be wired with 12.  So I think the 14 is just to the light and outlet.

From what I have been reading I am assuming that this needs to have new wire run to both spots.  Any opinions?

And just out of curiosity how important is changing it for the light fixture - it is just a small single bulb fixture.

Comment: You measured the bare wire and not the insulation?  Most cables/single wires(in conduit) will have the gauge number marked on the insulation every foot or two.

Comment: Yes I measured the bare wire.   The wire in this house is old and all of is just white insulation with no markings on the wire that I can see.   Plus this is in the wall so a little hard to get too.

Answer (score 2):

14 gauge wire is not allowed on 20 amp circuits.  Does not matter if just for a small light.

Since kitchen outlets are also on this circuit, you probably do not have the choice of just putting a 15 amp breaker instead of the 20 amp breaker to make this circuit up to code.

If not a long run, replacing the 14 gauge wire with 12 gauge should not be too hard.  You might be able to use the 14g wire to pull the new 12g wire.